# fit_generator for autoencoders produces weird results

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, batch-processing

I am using functional version of keras model to train my autoencoder network and was using model.fit() function from keras as follows:

```
model.fit(train_data, train_ground_truth_data, validation_data = (validation_data, validation_ground_truth_data), epochs=1000, batch_size=40, callbacks=callbacks)
```

I was able to train the model this way. At this time, I was converting the data to float32 datatype at once using the following command:
train_data = train_data.astype('float32') / 255.

Because I have a large amount of data that would cause the RAM to run out of memory when converting it to *float32*, I decided that I would convert it in batches and use fit_generator to train my model. The following code loads the image and its ground truth in batches.

```
 def imageLoader(data, ground_truth_data, batch_size):
        L = data.shape[0] # there are equal numbers of images in data and its ground_truth_data
        #this line is just to make the generator infinite, keras needs that    
        while True:
            batch_start = 0
            batch_end = batch_size

            while batch_start < L:
                limit = min(batch_end, L)
                #print(limit)
                X = data[batch_start:limit, :].astype('float32') / 255.         

                Y = ground_truth_data[batch_start:limit, :].astype('float32') / 255.

                yield (X,Y) #a tuple with two numpy arrays with batch_size samples

                batch_start += batch_size   
                batch_end += batch_size
```

I use the following line of code to train it using fit_generator function from keras.

```
model.fit_generator(imageLoader(train_data,train_ground_truth_data, batch_size), validation_data = imageLoader(validation_data, validation_ground_truth_data, batch_size), epochs=1000, steps_per_epoch = math.ceil(num_samples / batch_size), validation_steps = math.ceil(num_validation_samples / batch_size), callbacks=callbacks)
```

I wanted to check that this method of training using fit_generator() will work the same way as fit() function, I used a small dataset and tested it using both of these methods. But the problem is, the model does not train when I use the fit_generator. It was training properly when I used model.fit_generator() function using the imageLoader() function. The validation loss and training loss is constant after 2 epochs.

Is it not a correct way to do it using the fit_generator() ?

Comment: How many data have you used to test your model? In other word, what is the value of `data.shape[0]`?